# enable scripting within docker image

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I can start elasticsearch with Kibana using the following 2 docker commands...

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name elasticsearch-pb elasticsearch
docker run -d -p 5601:5601 --name kibana-pb --link elasticsearch-pb:elasticsearch -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200 kibana
```

But how do I start es with script support using docker?

Usually this is done by adding 2 lines to elasticsearch.yml file.

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

how do I change the config file within docker image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a custom image that includes those options.

Create a directory for your docker image

```
mkdir my_elasticsearch
cd my_elasticsearch
```

Create an `elasticsearch.yml` with all the options including

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

Create a `Dockerfile` that copies the config file.

```
from elasticsearch
copy elastcsearch.yml /container/path/to/elasticsearch.yml
```

Build and tag the image

```
docker build -t my/elasticsearch .
```

Then run your image

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name elasticsearch-pb my/elasticsearch
```

You might want to publish your image to the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) or another registry so you only need to build it once.

You can also use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) to manage the build process and multiple containers.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create your own elasticsearch image, through a Dockerfile starting with the [official elasticsearch image](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/).

```
FROM elasticsearch:5
COPY myconfig /path/to/elasticsearch.yml
```

That way, your image can start an elasticsearch container with the right configuration pre-setted.