# ElasticSearch group and distribute to buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I am quite new to elasticsearch but it seems that there is no easy way to create aggregation and distribute doc_count to buckets once previous aggregation is done. 
For example I have below  set of data and I would like to create 4 buckets and group profiles that have specific numbers of transactions between the buckets.

Total number of profiles should be distributed to below buckets, where each bucket outlines min and max number of transactions that one profile could have.

number of profiles that has 0-1 transaction

number of profiles that has 2-5 transactions

number of profiles that has 6-20 transactions

number of profiles that has 20+ transactions

```
[
  {
    "profileId": "AVdiZnj6YuzD-vV0m9lx",
    "transactionId": "sdsfsdghfd"
  },
  {
    "profileId": "SRGDDUUDaasaddsaf",
    "transactionId": "asdadscfdvdvd"
  },
  {
    "profileId": "AVdiZnj6YuzD-vV0m9lx",
    "transactionId": "sdsacfsfcsafcs"
  }
]



Below request would show number of transactions per each profile but additional bucket grouping is required in order to group profiles to respective buckets using doc_cont.

    {   "size":0,
        "aggs" : {
            "profileTransactions" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : "profileId"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    "buckets": [
                {
                   "key": "AVdiZnj6YuzD-vV0m9lx",
                   "doc_count": 2
                },
      {
                   "key": "SRGDDUUDaasaddsaf",
                   "doc_count": 1
                }

                ]
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could do additional grouping with the help of [pipeline bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html). The [value count aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) is used since bucket aggregation is checked against a numeric field. This query will require **ES 2.x** version.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_profileId0": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "profileId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_profile_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "profileId"
          }
        },
        "range_0-1_bucket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalTransaction": "total_profile_count"
            },
            "script": "totalTransaction < 2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "unique_profileId1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "profileId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_profile_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "profileId"
          }
        },
        "range_2-5_bucket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalTransaction": "total_profile_count"
            },
            "script": "totalTransaction >= 2 && totalTransaction <= 5"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "unique_profileId2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "profileId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_profile_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "profileId"
          }
        },
        "range_6-20_bucket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalTransaction": "total_profile_count"
            },
            "script": "totalTransaction >= 6 && totalTransaction <= 20"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "unique_profileId3": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "profileId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_profile_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "profileId"
          }
        },
        "range_20_more_bucket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalTransaction": "total_profile_count"
            },
            "script": "totalTransaction > 20"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) for this to work, add following two lines to the YML file

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

and **restart** each node.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added note regarding dynamic scripting, let me know if you still get the error

Comment: "attributes": {
            "script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs:true": "true",
            "script.aggs:true": "true",
            "script.inline:true": "true",
            "script.groovy.sandbox.enabled:true": "true",
            "script.indexed:true": "true",
            "script.disable_dynamic:false": "true",
            "script.search:true": "true"
         },

Comment: which version of ES you are using? Did you restart the node?

Comment: I have edited the answer, add script.inline: on and script.indexed: on. refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711168/elasticsearch-dynamic-scripting-disabled)

Comment: my version is {
   "name": "DevNode",
   "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
   "cluster_uuid": "hKFuVFl3T5Kwq2tPRaYrkQ",
   "version": {
      "number": "2.4.1",
      "build_hash": "c67dc32e24162035d18d6fe1e952c4cbcbe79d16",
      "build_timestamp": "2016-09-27T18:57:55Z",
      "build_snapshot": false,
      "lucene_version": "5.5.2"
   },
   "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: Seems that ES did import configuration as it

Comment: Did you change *script.inline: true* to *script.inline: on*?

Comment: Atributes are visible in case I do GET _nodes/process?pretty    "attributes": {
            "script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs:true": "true",
            "script.aggs:true": "true",
            "script.inline:true": "true",
            "script.engine.groovy.inline.update:true": "true",
            "script.groovy.sandbox.enabled:true": "true",
            "script.indexed:true": "true",
            "script.disable_dynamic:false": "true",
            "script.search:true": "true"
         },

Comment: I am sorry this is frustrating, but 1) do you have script.inline: on in your yml file? 2)could you please restart the node after adding that line?

Comment: I am starting it from docker my parameters are     command: elasticsearch -Des.network.bind_host=0.0.0.0 -Des.node.name="DevNode" -Des.node.script.inline:on -Des.node.script.indexed:on -Des.node.script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs:on -Des.node.script.aggs:on -Des.node.script.disable_dynamic:false -Des.node.script.search:true -Des.node.script.groovy.sandbox.enabled:true -Des.node.script.engine.groovy.inline.update:true

Comment: i stop docker container and start it once i change command line

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638298/enable-scripting-within-docker-image) should help you, I believe ES reads scripting options from config file only

Comment: Thanks, finally I was able to get response from ES but it is not what i was hoping.  I would need profiles grouped by the number of transactions and overall summary for each bucket. i got http://prntscr.com/ct2rzu        number of profiles that has 0-1 transaction

number of profiles that has 2-5 transactions

number of profiles that has 6-20 transactions

number of profiles that has 20+ transactions

Comment: I did not understand. could you add the ouput you want to the question? the above answer groups the profiles into 4 buckets you asked for. Do you need something extra?

Comment: My response should be something as "aggregations": {
    "count of unique_profileIds that have <2": 1,
    "count of unique_profileIds that have 2-5": 2,
   "count of unique_profileIds that have 5-20": 0,
   "count of unique_profileIds that have >20": 10,
  } there is not need for buckets in each unique profile id

Comment: You are getting the count, aren't you? I do not think you can get rid of buckets