# doc_count sub aggregation script

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an aggregation which gives back a number of buckets.   I'd like to further run a script which analyzes all the doc_counts and groups them into categories.   Can someone give me an example of how to do this?

For example....

```
              "aggregations": {
          “updates_by_account: {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "fbf60d008f0b2f9b3d1d8f1f7fe6e4262662a04c9bcbcc20d92316daade3c25c",
               "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "916129338fb099792f7b1f414868d45c3fd1a0feb89e1bbeafe24bdb496bec0b",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "f1b256be780d983549e968f187daef882999fd05889dcab7f1c8c4769ed0996b",
               "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
```

my query looks like this

```
    {   
         "aggs" : {
                    "updates_by_account": {
                             "terms": {
                                    "script" : "doc[‘account_number’].value"
                              }
                    }
    }
```

I'd like to do something like:

Number of users with 0-5 updates: 4
Number of users with 6-10 updates: 7
Number of users with 11 or more updates: 12

etc

Comment: I solved [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942110/elasticsearch-group-and-distribute-to-buckets/39949579#39949579) like this. Let me know if this does not help

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.   Thank you.

Comment: glad I could help